# Grep for a file with a specific name

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

In my repository I have several files, including two specific JAR files named as follows:

- backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
- backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar.original

I need to get only the first one, and I need to fetch it only with its name: "**backend**". The version is not static; it can change.

So I have done this:

```
ls | grep 'backend'
```

But this one get me both of them, so I need to grep for files beginning with **backend** and ending by **.jar**.

How can I use this?

Comment: `echo backend*.jar`? [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Please read the documentation for `grep`. Also, learn about wildcards and regular expressions.

Comment: @ForceBru: It would be better to point to duplicates here on Stack Overflow (so this question can be closed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ls | grep '^backend.*.jar$'
```

`$` means, that there are no symbols after `r` in `jar`.

Comment: It should be `.*`. Also, *...file beginning with backend...*, so you might want to add `^`.

Comment: And guess what happens if you happen to have a file named: `^backend.foo.jar$` in your directory. You really don't want the pathname expansion to take place => use single quotes around the regex.

Answer (score 2):

[Don't use the output of `ls` for scripting](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Use `find` instead:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'backend*.jar'
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, without using `grep`:

```
ls backend*.jar
```